# Pg-promise : Empty promise

Tags: promise, generator, bluebird, pg-promise

I am currently working on a generator with pg-promise and Bluebird :

```
function * getOrRegisterCurrentFriendIfProvided(t)
```

that should return either a empty promise (if t.ctx.context is undefined)
NB : a example in pure bluebird :

```
yield new Promise(function (resolve) { resolve({}) });
```

or call another function (that provides a result ) :

```
yield t.task.call(params.friend,anotherFunction);
```

Any way to express my empty Promise with pg-promise (without use a query like t.none("BYPASS QUERY") ) ?

With the example below, when I do this :

```
db.task(getOrRegisterCurrentFriendIfProvided)
   .then(function(result){
        console.log(result) // gives me undefined
   })
```

I got undefined. I am sure that the problem occurer when t.ctx.context is undefined

EDIT : The full code :

```
function * getOrRegisterCurrentFriendIfProvided(t) {
let params = t.ctx.context;

if (params.hasOwnProperty("friend")) {
    yield t.task.call(params.friend,anotherFunction);
} else {
    // returns a empty result ( {} )  promise , just to make promise chain not angry
    yield new Promise(function (resolve) { resolve({}) });
}

}
```

Comment: You need to add `getOrRegisterCurrentFriendIfProvided` implementation to your question, otherwise it is impossible to know what you are doing and where the problem is.

Comment: Just added and found a solution but it is maybe not the best one

Comment: The issue is now obvious - you are not returning anything anywhere in your callback, so what did you expect to be returned from the task? :)

Comment: just wonder if there is a another way than return t.batch([]); inside the generator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting `undefined` from the task is because your callback isn't returning anything. Change it to the following:

```js
function * getOrRegisterCurrentFriendIfProvided(t) {
    let params = t.ctx.context;
    if (params.hasOwnProperty("friend")) {
        return yield t.task.call(params.friend, anotherFunction);
    }
}
```

I also removed the `else` part because it is useless there, for the way you use it, i.e. returning nothing is the same as resolving with `undefined`.

**UPDATE**

`pg-promise` no longer supports generators, because newer NodeJS made `async` syntax standard, which is more suitable for the task callbacks.

Comment: thanks. Just have to have if inside next my next then ... I doubted to make it or make the generator returns an empty object value : {}